# Japanese StackOverflow should be moved to "Technology" category

Tags: discussion

[This page](https://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized) shows the Japanese StackOverflow as "uncategorized". It should be listed in the "Technology" tab, along with the English and the Portuguese language sites.